# Netty 4, Java 7 JVM SIGSEGV crash under load

Tags: java, jvm, netty

I have a binary protocol implemented with Netty that is being performance tested, and the JVM is crashing with the below report.  I do not know how to repeat the crash, but it does happen regularly and only under heavy load.  I have the following dependencies:

- java 7.0_51-b13
- netty 4.0.18_Final
- fedora 20

It appears that the array copy is occurring in the nioEventLoopGroup thread.  The performance test I am running is sending a large number of small messages over ~50 TCP connections.  Where a large number is about 1 million 200 byte messages per connection. Each message has 2 response messages sent back.

This is what I am doing to create Netty:

Bootstrap:

```
m_serverBootstrap.group(m_eventLoopGroup)
 .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
 .localAddress(m_config.getSmppPort())
 .childAttr(InternalAttributeKeys.METRICS, m_metricRegistry)
 .childHandler(new CustomServerChannelInitializer());

m_serverBindChannelFuture = m_serverBootstrap.bind().sync();
```

CustomerServerChannelInitializer

```
protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
    log.info("initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {} {} ",ch,this);
    ch.pipeline()
    .addLast(new IpFilterHandler())
    .addLast(new ProtocolEncoder())
    .addLast(new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(4 * 1024, 0, 4, -4, 0))
    .addLast(new ProtocolDecoder())
    .addLast(new WindowingHandler())
    .addLast(new SequenceNumberAssignmentHandler())
    .addLast("idleState", new IdleStateHandler(idleTime, idleTime, idleTime))
    .addLast("idleDisconnect", m_idleDisconnectHandler)
    .addLast("auth", m_authHandler)
    .addLast("catchall", new CatchallHandler(false));
    ch.config().setAllocator(PooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT);
    ch.config().setAutoRead(true);
    log.info("finished initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {} {} ",ch,this);
}
```

After initial connection the pipeline is altered again in the authHandler

```
@Override
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, CustomMessage msg) throws Exception {
    ResponseMessage response = auth(msg,ctx);
    ctx.pipeline().replace("auth", "msghandler", new MessageHandler());
    ctx.pipeline().replace("idleState", "inactivityPeriod", new IdleStateHandler());
    ctx.pipeline().addAfter("msghandler", "responsehandler", new ResponseHandler());
    ctx.pipeline().addAfter("responsehandler", "heartbeat", new HeartbeatHandler());
    ctx.pipeline().addAfter("heartbeat", "disconnect", new DisconnectHandler());
    ctx.channel().closeFuture().addListener(new CleanupChannelFutureListener(ctx));
    ctx.writeAndFlush(response);
}
```

jvm report.  I have a detailed report if it helps http://pastebin.com/RV0KqPMf 
If the JMX threads in the detailed report are bothering you, I can and have reproduced the issue without them.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007ffa9eb18eaa, pid=1731, tid=140710808540928
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# v  ~StubRoutines::jbyte_disjoint_arraycopy
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /home/user/dir/core or core.1731
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007ff9fc06f800):  JavaThread "nioEventLoopGroup-2-12" [_thread_in_Java, id=1912, stack(0x00007ff9c9b25000,0x00007ff9c9c26000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x00007ff987df7715
```

What is the best way to find out what is causing this SIGSEGV in the JVM?

Comment: Netty 4.0.21 is out. Have you tried that on the off chance it fixes it?

Comment: Using Netty 4.0.21 may have fixed it.  Previously a connection would receive ~150,000 messages (200bytes) and then crash the JVM.  But it appears to get past that now and behave as expected.  Thanks!  Any idea what the fix may have been?

Comment: No idea. Just when I get a bug like this I always make sure I'm using the latest version. If you reported it to the netty devs it is probably the first thing they would suggest.

Comment: I can reliably reproduce this now.  I found that the issue was present in 4.0.18.Final and 4.0.19.Final.  It was not in 4.0.20.Final and 4.0.21.Final.  So the fix was likely in 4.0.20.Final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading from Netty 4.0.18.Final to 4.0.20.Final fixed this issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely a Netty bug.

Netty 4.x heavily uses Unsafe API - Oracle JDK internal API that allows raw memory access.
See [PlatformDependent0.java](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/common/src/main/java/io/netty/util/internal/PlatformDependent0.java) from Netty sources.

The crash log tells that the problem happens inside `Unsafe.copyMemory` call where the target is a `byte[]` array in Java Heap young generation, and the source points to an unmapped memory region. Most likely this is caused by an attempt to get bytes from a native buffer that has been previously released. There are no sanity checks inside Unsafe API, so any misuse typically ends up with a JVM crash.